# Creating a Post Route with ASP.NET CORE 2.0 WebAPI parameter is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm sending POST from PostMan: [image: screenshot of postman settings]
And the parameter keeps coming up as null. From what I read, changing `Post([FromBody]Models.Question value)` and setting the model should be able to handle the json parameter coming in. I think I am missing a setting or I don't understand how to handle the json data correctly.

QuestionsController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace quiz_backend.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Questions")]
    public class QuestionsController : Controller
    {
        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]Models.Question value)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Model is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace quiz_backend.Models
{
    public class Question
    {
        public string Text{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your request body, it seems that your request payload is `{"test":"test"}`. It should be `{"Text": "text sample"} in order to match the object property `Text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property on your model is `Text` while the request body property you are sending is `"test"`. No wonder they will not bind and you get `null`. The case does not matter here but you have different word all together.

Comment: Thank you!! I was working on it at night and completely missed that!